# What's the difference between "HAND OFF" and "HAND OVER"?

Tags: terminology

I think "HAND OVER" is a whole process of transfering radar idenrification between 2 controllers, and "HAND OFF" is a term used by the transfering controller(not receiving controller) when doing HAND OVER.

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S. Air Traffic Controllers ***initiate* handoffs** and ***receive* handoffs**.  Perhaps the term "hand over" is general term applied to the process of making/receiving a "handoff."

Here is the definition of "Handoff" from the Pilot/Controller's Glossary in the [FAA JO Order 7110.65W](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf), Air traffic Controller's handbook:

> HANDOFF
>   −
>     An  action  taken  to  transfer  the  radar
>   identification  of  an  aircraft  from  one  controller  to
>   another  if  the  aircraft  will  enter  the  receiving
>   controller’s airspace 
>   and radio communications with
>   the aircraft will be transferred.

I am unable to find the term "Hand Over" in the 7110.65W.

Comment: "Hand over" might refer to the process of transferring control of an *entire control position* to a fresh controller—what the FAA calls a "position relief briefing"—rather than transfer (between two control positions) of radar identification of a single target. I seem to recall hearing the term "hand over" used in that context in a documentary about NATS (UK).